# Process is terminated due to StackOverflowExeption - C#

Tags: c#, crash, stack-overflow

I have this problem with my code I cant fix.

I am making a quiz, but the questions mustnt be asked twice so I avoided that, but when it runs out of options it crashes.

It also could be the code after it, but I dont think so.

Here is my code:

```
private static void chooseQuestion()
{
    Random randomQuestion = new Random();

    int returnValue = randomQuestion.Next(1, 3);

    switch (returnValue)
    {
        case 1:
            if (randomValues.questionOneChosen != 1)
            {
                questionOne();
            }else
            {
                chooseQuestion();
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (randomValues.questionTwoChosen != 1)
            {
                questionTwo();
            }else
            {
                chooseQuestion();
            }
            break;
    }

    endQuiz();
}
```

and here is what is after it:

```
private static void endQuiz()
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine();
    text.centered("You completed the QUIZ, well done!");
    Console.WriteLine();
    text.centeredWrite("Press ENTER to go back to the menu");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == "")
    {
        Menu.main();
    }else
    {
        endQuiz();
    }
}
```

If you need more code to help me, please ask me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each time a line is read from endQuiz you call again to endQuiz, that will lead finally to an StackOverflow, also you call chooseQuestion from chooseQuestion, another source for StackOverflow. You must redesign all your logic, get a main loop for your code and from there call functions which return results, then you will have no stack overflows.

Comment: I think the issue is in endQuiz().
What are you trying to do there? You are reading a line from the Console, and then if it's not empty line then you're re-calling `endQuiz()`?

Comment: You should rethink your design. What if you want to add more questions?

Comment: `endQuiz` is never reached...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A StackOverflowException on StackOverflow, nice!
Does Menu.main() end up calling chooseQuestion()?
When a function is called, a new entry on the stack is created with room for all its local variables and the address to return to when it returns. If a function calls itself (recursive call), its original stack entry is not released. If it calls itself often enough without returning, the stack will eventually run out of room and give this exception. Having said that, the stack is pretty big - I think the default is 1 megabyte - so you need a lot of recursive calls to exhaust it.

You've got two functions which both call themselves. If they do it often enough, you'll run out of stack space. Just replace the recursive calls with a loop. Here's your first function:

```
private static void chooseQuestion() 
{    
    bool endQuizChosen = false;
    while ( !endQuizChosen ) {
        Random randomQuestion = new Random();
        int returnValue = randomQuestion.Next(1, 3);  
        // ... the rest of the function ...
        endQuizChosen = endQuiz();
    }
}
```

and edit `endQuiz()` to not call itself but to return `true` if user wants to stop and `false` if they want to go on.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is never getting set.

```
randomValues.questionOneChosen
```

So whatever it is, if it's not 1 or 2 the method is going to call itself again. It's probably always zero.

Comment: no that is another piece of code: 
`class randomValues
    {
        public static int questionOneChosen;
        public static int questionTwoChosen;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Your `chooseQuestion` method's logic goes like this:

```
a. Pick a 1 or 2, randomly
b. If 1, and I haven't asked question 1 yet, show question 1
c. if 1, and I have asked question 1, go to step (a)
d. repeat (b) and (c) for question 2
...
```

once you answer both questions, you try to get another random question.  But there are no more questions available.  So you recurse into an exception.

Don't write your logic this way.  Use a collection, and remove the item from the collection after you've shown that question.  When the collection is empty, you're done.

Comment: But when the switch doent pick anything it would just go to the next line right?

There it is told to go to the next piece of code

Comment: no, your switch will fall to the `else` statements, and call your method again.  You'll never make it to `endQuiz()`.  You can (and should) debug the code and watch it run yourself

Comment: oh I see, thank you so much, but do you know how to write my code than?  I am just new to C# so I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: You should start by rethinking your logic, then work on the C# implementation

Comment: sure thing.  On this site, if you find an answer that helped you, its good to accept that answer by clicking the green checkbox.  Once you have your logic worked out, you can come back with specific C# questions regarding your implementation.